# Android Studio 0.8.14 Can't resolve symbol 'Bundle'

Tags: android, android-studio

i am new to android studio, now am just install the android studio and create sample project.It shows error in Java file like Can't resolve symbol bundle,menu etc.about this am attached the screen shot.SDK and JDK path in correct location but i don't know why this issue come.

[image: Android Studio workspace]

Comment: Try to `Sync Project with Gradle Files` in your menu toolbar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to `Sync Project with Gradle Files` in your menu toolbar.

[image: Like this]

Answer (score 11):

File > Invalidate Caches / Restart... and Invalidate and Restart to solve the issue.

Comment: Yup, that's the only thing that worked. But can you please explain *why* this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Hit the 'Sync Project with Grandle Files' button  [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03HFi.png)
i think its a bug 
for me it works sometimes :D