# Android Studio 2.1 class reference errors

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

Android Studio and avd is running, my computer was accidentally shutdown. I reopen the computer and start android studio it show me something to update. After it updated, many reference errors occured.

I tried to remove android studio and reinstall it, errors still occurs.

Comment: You mean build -> clean project? (tried not work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work for me:

File > Invalidate Caches / Restart... and Invalidate and Restart to solve the issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29694075/3640398

Answer (score 0):

Try to `Sync Project` with Gradle Files in your `menu` toolbar.

[image]

Comment: Oh, sad tpo hear that, strange. Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100688/android-studio-suddenly-cannot-resolve-symbols maybe it can help !!